# I can't display the text after the icon

Tags: html, css, text, icons

I can't display text after the icon. I tried to use float but isn't working.

Can u help me to solve it please? I can't find the solve on google, i tried this before asking

CSS File:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    height: 70px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 100%;
}

i{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

i:hover{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Titlu</title>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/768cd38b76.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        <h1>Titlu</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `header {display: flex; }`

Comment: header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Just add that to the class and it should solve your problem. You can also remove margin-top in the "i" class to make you design neater.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).